# How to get Lorentz metric from a given light cone structure?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, time

Given a Lorentz metric it's usually easy to figure out how the the light cone structure looks like (e.g. by calculating the null geodesics).

But is there a straightforward way to determine the associated Lorentz metric based on a given light cone structure?

For example (see image below):
For a flat 2-dimensional manifold (M,g) we have these light cones that keep tilting to the left. The light cones also don't open up/ close (they remain open at 45 degrees while tilting). How must the metric g look like to get such a light cone structure?

PS: The generic flat metric $g=-(dt)^2+(dx)^2$ obviously doesn't yield this structure as the light cones don't tilt.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The light cone structure is associated with the conformal structure of the spacetime.
You'll need some additional information to fully determine the metric.

> The causal order C determines the conformal structure of space-time, or nine of the
> ten components of the metric. The measure on spacetime fixes the tenth component.
>
> David Finkelstein - "Space Time Code" (1969), Phys. Rev. 184, 1261 https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.184.1261
>
> https://www.davidritzfinkelstein.com/papers/Space-TimeCode.pdf